# Is it possible to entangle 2 sets of entangled pairs?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Say in Setup 1 I entangled electron A and electron B, then in Setup 2 I entangled electron C and electron D. Can I then entangle electron A with electron C? Is this consider an act of measurement especially if all particles are in superposition states? Would it matters if photons are used instead of electrons for this experiment?

Comment: interestingly spin would also be conserved if these A, B, C, D electrons are entangled four-way, wouldn't it? Once any 2 spin measurements are made, the last 2 spins are required to fill in the gap to preserve the sanctity of total spin. Does theory rule out entanglement within a system of more than 2 particles?

Comment: @James :  Does "sanctity of total spin" mean that   every state is an eigenstate of total spin in any direction?  That's false even for a system of one particle.

Comment: @WillO on the above I meant the final *measured* discrete UP and DOWN total spin of the system will be the same before and after all the newly created entangled particles' spins are all measured. Would this be correct?

Comment: @James :  What a one particle system in the state U+D?  Or a two particle system in the state UU+DD ?

Comment: @WillO Do you mean U+D as in the pre-measurement superposition of states? After the measurement, all superposition has collapsed, and each particle ends up with only a UP or DOWN observable spin outcome, right?